# How to append params to ajax request in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

i'm building a web app using Laravel, and i have to implement tag selection, like this one used by stackoverflow, loading options via ajax and if is not exist create it, i did choose Select2 jquery plugin, the problem i have with it, is cant get it to append parameters to the ajax url,

### Route :

```
 /tags/{tag}
```

how can i append the term of select to my url ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Select2 3.x, you can pass a function as the `ajax.url` option. It will be passed the current search term as the first parameter, which sounds like what you are looking for.

```
$element.select2({
   ...
    ajax: {
        url: function (term) {
            return '/tags/' + term;
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it works, but there is another parameter also appended automatically  tags/search/{term}?_=1415027037653 i dont know where this number come from ??

Comment: That's a cache-busting token that is added by jQuery. If you set `cache: false` in your ajax configuration, it should prevent it from being added.

Comment: no doesn't work ! i have set it to false with no luck!

Comment: My bad, you should set it to `true`. The default, for Select2, is `false`.